# R officer package body_add_img formatting

Tags: r, officer

I am using the R `officer` package to generate a word document based on an existing document template. There are locations within the template where imaged are inserted using `body_add_img`. Here is how I am implementing this within my script:

`doc<- doc %>% cursor_reach('FIGURE1HERE')%>% body_add_img(src=paste(box_path, pic_path, sep=''), width=2.1, height=1.4, pos = "on")`

The intent is to insert the image where the text FIGURE1HERE occurs within the template, shown here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inMGt.png)

However, when the image is inserted, the formatting and text are displaced:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QiL8.png)

I tried adjusting both the `pos` and `style` arguments, but did not have any luck.

Does anyone know how to utilize `body_add_img`, or another method, to insert images without disrupting the document formatting, and allowing "wrap-text"? I am open to other package suggestions, however I need to stay within an R environment. If there is any other information needed to answer this question, please ask. Thanks!